# Are surjective homomorphisms in lattices completely determined by their kernel?

Tags: lattice-orders

Let $L$ be a [lattice](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/lattice).

Let $\mathcal L$ denote a partition of $L$, and let $[a]$ denote the equivalence class presented by $a\in L$.

Further let $\wedge$ and $\vee$ be binary operations on $\mathcal L$ such that:

- $[a]\wedge[b]=[a\wedge b]$
- $[a]\vee[b]=[a\vee b]$

Then it is obvious that equipped with these operations $\mathcal L$ is a lattice itself and the function $\nu:L\to\mathcal L$ is a surjective homomorphism that has $[0]$ as kernel.

Further $[0]$ will serve as least element of $\mathcal L$ and $[1]$ as largest element of $\mathcal L$.

It is easy to prove that:$$\exists i\in[0] [a\vee i=b\vee i]\implies[a]=[b]\tag1$$

> My question is: is the opposite of $(1)$ also true?

I hope the answer is "yes", and that I am only bothered by a blind spot for that.

If it would be "no" then this would lead to a partition that is properly finer by stating that: $$\exists i\in[0] [a\vee i=b\vee i]\iff a\sim b\tag1$$

which would also be a lattice. Then again there is a surjective homomorphism having $[0]$ as kernel.

So another way of asking would be:

> are surjective homomorphisms completely determined by their kernel?

Comment: Are you claiming that the quotient of a lattice by any equivalence class is again a lattice? That's not true. Only if the equivalence is a congruence. Any way, the class of 0 doesn't determine the other classes (as it would in groups, for example). As a counter-example take a chain with more than two elements, say $0<a<1$; you can have a two different congruences in which $[0]=\{0\}$: the trivial congruence, in which each class is a singleton, an the the congruence that relates $a$ and $1$. But perhaps I'm misunderstanding you.

Comment: @amrsa No, I am not claiming that. The fact that $\wedge$ and $\vee$ on $\mathcal L$ are well-defined assures that we are dealing with a congruence. I am not giving definitions there but properties. I will have a look at the counterexample that you gave. Thank you for that.

Comment: If my counter-example is useful, then [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2260586/generalization-of-normal-subgroups-and-ideals/2263304#2263304) is related; Keith Kearnes gives a very nice answer from which it follows that lattices are not congruence-regular (that is, congruences are not determined by each class, or any class, in general).

Comment: @amrsa Your counterexample is effective as answer to my question. My request is that you write an answer to my question. That enables me to accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently, the property that you're asking about is congruence-regularity.
A congruence is regular if one class determines the others;
an algebra is congruence-regular if each of its congruences is regular;
a variety is congruence-regular if each of its members is congruence-regular.
The archetypical example is the one of groups.

Lattices are not congruence-regular.
For example, take $C$ to be the three-element chain, $C = \{0,a,1\}$, with $0<a<1$.
Then
$$\theta_1 = \Delta_C = \{(x,x):x \in C\}$$
is a congruence with $[0]_{\theta_1}=\{0\}$;
but
$$\theta_2 = \{(0,0),(a,a),(a,1),(1,a),(1,1)\}$$
is another congruence with $[0]_{\theta_2} = \{0\}$.
So the class of $0$ doesn't determine the congruence.
Notice also that $0$ doesn't play a special role here, so if we had a longer chain, and take a "middle" element $x$, in the sense that there would be at least two elements below $x$ or at least two elements above, again we could construct two different congruences such that the class of $x$ would be a singleton.
For lattices which are not chains, counter-examples could also be given, but of course, there are cases in which these congruences are indeed regular (for example, the four-element lattice that is not a chain is congruence-regular).

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2260586/generalization-of-normal-subgroups-and-ideals) is related, and in particular, the answer given by Keith Kearnes points to characterizations of congruence-regular varieties, and related results.